# Scrolling in Pageblocktable

Tags: pageblocktable, scrolling

Is there a way to implement horizontal and vertival scroll to a pageblocktable similar to the ones in ListViews?

Similar to ListViews means vertical scrolling is only for the data and not for header and header and body share the same horizontal scrolling .

I tried;

```
<script>
var idx = "{!$Component.myPb.displayTable}";
idx = idx +':tb'; // Get the body of page block table
document.getElementById(idx).style = "overflow:auto;height: 250px;";
</script>
```

But it is not helping.

**Update:**
I tried the StickyTableHeader mentioned in [Eric's Answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/149437/22234) which is working great but only problem is if overflowing horizontally it miss-aligns the header and body

***After Horizontal scroll***
 [image]

***After Horizontal-Vertical scroll***[image]

Comment: You have two answers that took the time to provide you a solution yet you have not awarded the bounty. As it stand the bounty will not be awarded to anyone that took the time to help you. Can you please either select and answer, up vote the one that helped you most, or award the bounty?

Comment: You were on 45 minutes ago. Can you let us know why you did not award the bounty so we can help you get this answered?

Comment: Seems is because inside a container with fixed width. Either take it out of the container or see: https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders/issues/1 (goto March 30 2013 answer on)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quickest way to do this would be to use StickyTableHeaders. (Most reliable solution I have used) and provides the most standard like UI compared to other solutions. Datatables.net is also a great resource if you want to add search and filtering. I like it much better that jQuery data tables.

https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders

Here is a MVR code for you to try using a set height div and the Account object. I have to placed the JS in a static resource for this example.

```
<apex:page id="examplePage" standardController="Account" recordSetVar="acc">

    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.StickyHeaders)}"/>

    <style>
        .squeeze {
            overflow: auto;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="squeeze">
            <apex:pageBlockTable id="pgb_table" value="{!acc}" var="a">
                <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!a.Name}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

            <script>
                $('[id$=pgb_table]').stickyTableHeaders({scrollableArea: $('.squeeze')});
            </script>
        </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

Image on load

[image]

Image after scrolling a few

[image]

Horizontal scrolling should happen by default.

Comment: Hi Eric. Thanks for the answer. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: @SaumyaRanjanSatapathy - How did it work for you??

Comment: Eric, This api works great. Actually this is what I was looking for. Sorry for this late replay as I was stuck with some other issues. And sure I will add the bounty again and award it.

Comment: Just one problem I am seeing with this api, when I set width of the table and then I scroll horizontally or vertically. I am updating the screenshot in the questions.

Comment: @SaumyaRanjanSatapathy did you add any css??

Comment: No. I added https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders/blob/master/js/jquery.stickytableheaders.js along with jQuery 1.11.1 and the style,apex:outputpannel,javascript as you mentioned. Are you not getting the sames issue?

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to implement this requirement is using [Jquery datatable plugin](https://datatables.net/). It will give you horizontal and vertical scrolling including many other functionality. Here is a sample Visualforce Page. Hope this helps.

```
 <apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts" >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        div.dataTables_wrapper {
            width: 800px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>    
    <apex:pageBlock id="thePageBlock" >
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="theSection">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" width="100%" var="acc" id="theTable" styleClass="opp-table">
                <apex:column value="{!acc.name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!acc.AccountNumber}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!acc.AnnualRevenue}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!acc.Fax}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!acc.phone}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!acc.AccountSource}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!acc.BillingStreet}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!acc.BillingCity}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!acc.BillingState}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!acc.BillingPostalCode}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!acc.BillingCountry}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!acc.OwnerId}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!acc.ParentId}"/>                
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
        j$(document).ready(function () {
            j$('[id$=theTable]').DataTable( {
                "bSort" : false,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "scrollY": 200,
                "scrollX": true
            } );
        });  
    </script>    
</apex:page>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Saroj. I tried Datatables jquery api. I liked its ui even more. But I was not able to bind the table buttons with the server side actions, like the next and previous buttons should invoke next() and preivious() of standard set controller. Even the page size, sorting and searching should go to controller and fetch the data instead of operating on the data that gets downloaded when the page loads. Could you help me doing that?

Answer (score 0):

StickyTableHeaders jquery api is definitely easy and concrete approach if your page do not over flow horizontally.

As my table had many columns and rows which made the container div overflow horizontally and vertically, so I switched to HTML tables.

[SampeTable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40862042/4087536)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css"></link>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Scroll Example</title>
  <style>
    .scroll-example {
      display: block;
      margin-right: 20px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        min-width:100px;
        max-width:100px;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    td:hover i{
        display: block;
        float:right;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    i{
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
<div style="overflow: hidden;width: 400px;">
  <table id="target" class="scroll-example" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <tr>
        <td class="col11">HHHHHHHHHHHHH</td>
        <td class="col2">HHHHHHHHHHH</td>
        <td class="col3">HHHHHHHHHHH</td>
        <td class="col4">HHHHHHHHHHH</td>
        <td class="col5">HHHHHHHHHHH</td>
        <td class="col6">HHHHHHHHHHH</td>
        <td class="col7" width="20px"     style="border-color: white;"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table id="source" class="scroll-example" style="overflow: scroll;height: 80px;">
    <tr>
        <td class="col1"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
        <td class="col2"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
        <td class="col1"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
        <td class="col1"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
        <td class="col1"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
        <td class="col1"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
        <td class="col2"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
        <td class="col1"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
        <td class="col1"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
        <td class="col1"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
        <td class="col1"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
        <td class="col2"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
        <td class="col1"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
        <td class="col1"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
        <td class="col1"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
        <td class="col1"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>AAAAAAAAAAA</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script>
  (function() {
    var target = $("#target");
    $("#source").scroll(function() {
      target.prop("scrollTop", this.scrollTop)
            .prop("scrollLeft", this.scrollLeft);
    });
  })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work with CSS alone.

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .scrollable {
      overflow-y: auto; /* make it scrollable if needed */
      height: 20.5em;   /* non-integer height should cut a row in half-ish to visually let the user know it's scrollable in case of a mobile device or no scrollbar */
      display: inline-block;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      resize: vertical; /* optional. In my case, I needed users to be able to vertically resize the table display area */
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.100);
      border-width: 1px; 
      width: 100%;      /* For some reason, the table's container doesn't take up the full column unless this is present */
   }

   .scrollable thead {  /* Stick the header row to the top of the container */
      position: sticky;
      top: 0
   }

   .scrollable tfoot {  /* Stick the footer row to the bottom of the container */
      position: sticky;
      bottom: 0
   }
</style>
```

For the VisualForce, you'll wrap the pageblocktable with an output panel:

```
<apex:outputPanel styleClass="scrollable">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! ListItems}" var="i">
        ...
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

[image]