# Scroll to a new item in a pageBlockTable

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable, scrolling

I have a few `pageBlockTable`s which are set up to be scrollable. (See this answer [Scrolling in Pageblocktable](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148322/scrolling-in-pageblocktable/353493#353493) for a CSS-only way to do this, since someone's Googling this right now, I'm sure.)

The new feature I'd like to implement is that, when the user hits the Add New button, I'd like the row which is dynamically created for adding a new record to scroll into view. Javascript has a `scrollIntoView()` method which would probably come into play here but these elements are not simply hidden until used but are instead dynamically created so I can't really know the ID ahead of time. Does Visualforce/APEX have some sort of functionality for this?

In case it's important, I'm not using the `Rendered` attribute for this. The row where the user enters data for the new record is a dummy object I added to the end of the list which the `pageBlockTable` is based on and some logic within the `Pageblocktable` to use `InputField` instead of `OutputField` for the dummy object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scrollIntoView, you just have to be selective (pun intended) about it. Here's a copy-paste example for you to get started:

```
<apex:page controller="q358473">
    <style type="text/css">
        .scrollable {
        overflow-y: auto; /* make it scrollable if needed */
        height: 20.5em;   /* non-integer height should cut a row in half-ish to visually let the user know it's scrollable in case of a mobile device or no scrollbar */
        display: inline-block;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        resize: vertical; /* optional. In my case, I needed users to be able to vertically resize the table display area */
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.100);
        border-width: 1px; 
        width: 100%;      /* For some reason, the table's container doesn't take up the full column unless this is present */
        }
        
        .scrollable thead {  /* Stick the header row to the top of the container */
        position: sticky;
        top: 0
        }
        
        .scrollable tfoot {  /* Stick the footer row to the bottom of the container */
        position: sticky;
        bottom: 0
        }
    </style>
    
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:commandButton value="Add Row" reRender="form" action="{!addRow}"  oncomplete="document.querySelector('.scrollable tbody tr:last-child').scrollIntoView()" />
            <apex:pageBlockTable styleClass="scrollable" value="{!values}" var="input">
                <apex:column>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!input.value}" />
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public class q358473 {
    public class Wrapper {
        public string value { get; set; }
        Wrapper() {
            value = '';
        }
    }
    public Wrapper[] values { get; set; }
    public q358473() {
        values = new Wrapper[] { new Wrapper() };
    }
    public void addRow() {
        values.add(new Wrapper());
    }
}
```

Note that I simply lifted the CSS from the other answer you linked to, it seems to be just fine, but you can tweak it as you like.

The entire trick here is the oncomplete handler, where we query the last table row, and then use scrollIntoView.